# Solution .sln is of an unsupported format and may not open correctly

Tags: visual-studio-2012, expression-blend-5

Using Visual Studio 2012 Release Candidate and Expression Blend 5 for SL 5.

When attempting to open my project on Blend for SL 5 I came up with the warning of

> Solution .sln is of an unsupported format and may not open correctly.

How can this be solved?

Comment: did you manually modify your SLN file?

Comment: There's no way to answer this without more detail.  Did you try [asking the duck?](http://hwrnmnbsol.livejournal.com/148664.html)

Comment: [This search looks promising](https://www.google.com/#q=Solution+"unsupported+format+and+may+not+open+correctly")